# Css button activation

Tags: html, css

im not new to programming however, web design is not my strong suit by any means. Im currently using dreamweaver to design a website. On the site, when the button is pressed it is active. When I press another button such as "About" it sends you to the other page ( Which is a modified duplicate of this page ) however the "Home" button stays active even though im on the About page. Is this CSS script below assigned to that specific button somewhere? If it is assigned, what kind of file/what its location would be so that I can correct this. Thanks.

```
ul.navlink li a.active{
float:left;
padding:0 23px;
color:#000000;
background-color:#98AFC7;
display:block;
border-left:solid 2px #6D7B8D;
border-right:solid 2px #6D7B8D;
width:auto;
cursor:text;
}
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], not just a single CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you had posted some pictures but I will try to help.

What you are talking about, seems to me, to be the navegation menu. A lot of sites "Active" the link for the user know what page it is.

Normally, they have a css rules for the navegation link and another rules for the active link (class) in the navegation.

So, probably, if you look in the html of the "home" link, you will find a class or a ID on it, witch probably named as "active". All you have to do is remove it.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
 }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 }

#active {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Active nav</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="active">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I managed to find where the class was set to active.